How to crack excel binary sheets password
I have an Excel file (.xlsb) that contains password-locked sheets preventing from editing. The files are all saved in .bin, I have seen methods to remove the password when they are saved in .xml, but how to do it when they are saved in binary?
I tried to find the DPB as it is in the vbaProject.bin file but there is no such thing in the sheets

Worksheet.Unprotect Password:="Password"
